# How can I use Sagemaker built-in algorithms locally without estimators?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am interested in using the `AWS Sagemaker built-in algorithms` (or pre-trained models) without calling an Estimator class, just like I would do with `tensorflow` or `scikit-learn` **locally**.

I have found this but it uses an Estimator class to do the training:
https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html?highlight=local%20mode#local-mode

Is there a way or do I need to call an Estimator class every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Pretrained models

If you want to use a pretrained model, you don't have to go through the estimator because you already have the artifact of the model.

You can see a guide here: [Host a Pretrained Model on SageMaker](https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sagemaker-script-mode/pytorch_bert/deploy_bert_outputs.html#Host-a-Pretrained-Model-on-SageMaker)

In a nutshell, the turn it takes is to load the pre-trained model and package it in the usual `model.tar.gz` archive (which would be created following normal training with the estimator). If a custom inference script is required, there is the step of repacking the model.
At this point, it loads the uri of the model artifact and deploys the endpoint.

##### Extra: Using JumpStart (on SageMaker Studio)

A more interactive way is to use [SageMaker JumpStart](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/studio-jumpstart.html) on [SageMaker Studio](https://aws.amazon.com/it/sagemaker/studio/):[Use Amazon SageMaker Built-in Algorithms or Pre-trained Models](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/algos.html#algorithms-built-in-jumpstart)

---

### Built-in algorithms (not pretrained)

If the model is not pre-trained (so, will be trained), the [Estimator](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/estimators.html) (a high level interface for SageMaker training) must be used by definition.

See [Launch a Training Job Using the SageMaker Python SDK](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-parallel-sm-sdk.html):

> The SageMaker Python SDK supports managed training of models with ML
> frameworks such as TensorFlow and PyTorch. To launch a training job
> using one of these frameworks, you define a SageMaker TensorFlow
> estimator, a SageMaker PyTorch estimator, or a SageMaker generic
> Estimator to use the modified training script and model parallelism
> configuration